# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object after a modification to already working bit of code

Tags: php

So I am trying to work on this block of code for a personal project. This is an iteration of a sql query that is being passed by php.

```
1   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table 1`";
2   $result = $conn->query($sql);
3
4   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
5   // output data of each row
6   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
7   echo "id: " . $row["ID"]. " - Spell Name: " . $row["Spell Name"]. " - 
8   School " . $row["S"]. "<br>";
9   }
10  } else {
11  echo "0 results";
12  }
13  $conn->close();
```

When I run it, it gives

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line
```

I simply pulled this from the w3school tutorial, and replace the relevant column names. Just for the record, the dataset I am working with has roughly   entries

Comment: What line is in the error message?

Comment: The *actual* error message includes a line number.  Go to that line of code.  On that line of code you are trying to read a property from an object.  That object isn't actually an object when the code executes.  Go to where you *set* that object variable.  That operation isn't doing what you think or is failing in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped to have the line number, but so far, it looks like $conn is not defined. You don't have a connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The only line in that code where you're accessing a *property* is `$result->num_rows` on line 4, which suggests that `$result` is not an object.

Assuming `$conn` is a PDO connection, it means `PDO::query()` is returning false, since that is the only non-object value it can return. If the connection object itself was invalid, you'd see a fatal error from line 2 when you run the query.

In turn, this suggests that your SQL is not executing correctly. Since your query is a simple `SELECT * FROM...` statement, the likely reason is that **table 1** is either not a table, or is not accessible. Check by running the query against your database directly, using the MySQL command-line or similar.